# calculate fold change with three variables in R

Tags: r

I have a df

```
A      B       D
CA123  C1B1    10
CA123  C2B1    12
CA123  C3B1    5
CA456  C1B1    0.1
CA456  C2B1    0.05
CA456  C3B1    0.4
```

The df2 I am trying to generate is

```
A            C1B1  C2B1  C3B1 
CA123        0     1.2   0.5
CA456        0     0.5   4
```

The new column represents the fold change of column A in relation to C1B1 in column B.  There are two variants in column A and three variants in column B.

My current code is a bit cumbersome and would really appreciate anyone ideas on how to write it more elegantly.  I would be most interested in using gtools foldchange function. Thank you.

```
df2 <- df %>% pivot_wide(names_from = B, values_from = D) %>% 
mutate(C1B1 = (C1B1/C1B1)/C1B1, C2B1 = (C2B1/C1B1)/C1B1, C3B1 = (C3B1/C1B1)/C1B1) %>%
select(-c(B, D)) %>% pivot_longer(!c(A), names_to = B, values_to = D)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
group_by(foo, A) %>%
    mutate(D = C/nth(C, 1)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = A, names_from = B, values_from = D)
```